# Bootstrap carousel: how to know which slider it is when carousel is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel slide show which I can start (at browser refresh) and pause (`myBtn2`). When paused I need to know what is the current slider. How do I do that? Below my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <style>
    .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <button type="button" id="myBtn2" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Set</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="2000">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="item1 active"></li>
                    <li class="item2"></li>
                    <li class="item3"></li>
                    <li class="item4"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="jack-spades.png" alt="Jake Spade" width="460"
                            height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="jack_dimond.jpg" alt="Jack Diamond" width="460"
                            height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="queen.jpg" alt="Queen" width="460" height="345">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="queen_spades.jpg" alt="Queen Spade" width="460"
                            height="345">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Activate Carousel
                $("#myCarousel").carousel("cycle");

                // Click on the button to stop sliding
                $("#myBtn2").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel("pause");
                });

                // Enable Carousel Indicators
                $(".item1").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
                });
                $(".item2").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel(1);
                });
                $(".item3").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel(2);
                });
                $(".item4").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel(3);
                });

                // Enable Carousel Controls
                $(".left").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
                });
                $(".right").click(function() {
                    $("#myCarousel").carousel("next");
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please show a **minimal** representation of the markup that shows the problem, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

$("div.active") or $("li.active")

Comment: can you please explain more? Where and how should I use it?

Comment: When bootstrap animates the carousel it does so by placing the "active" class onto the li and div elements in sequence.

This is the jquery selector that will find the div containing the image(with class="item active"), or the li containing the relevant marker(with class="item<n> active"). 

Once you have this you can then use jQuery to investigate further, or to directly manipulate that div or item.